# Does 1/3 have a unique decimal representation?

Tags: real-numbers, decimal-expansion

I think it does, but I’m not sure.
And also there are rationals which have unique decimal representation besides irrational numbers.
Am i right?

Comment: Indeed $\frac13=0.3333333\dots$ is unique. Some numbers can have two decimal representations though, for example $1=0.99999\dots$

Comment: If we prohibit trailing 9s, then any real number has a unique decimal expansion (this is true in other bases too).

Comment: Your question seems to imply that you view $1/3$ as irrational. Do you?

Comment: No,i just want to say there are some rationals which have unique decimal representation like all the irrational numbers got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The only real numbers with more than one decimal representations are those that can be written as $\frac k{10^n}$, with $k\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ and $n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. Those that I described have exactly two decimal representations. For instance, $\frac{31}5\left(=\frac{62}{10}\right)$ has two decimal representations:$$6.2\text{ and }6.1999999\ldots$$

Comment: Is there anywhere I can find a proof of this?

Answer (score 0):

Any rational that repeats digits that are not all $9$ and not all $0$ has a unique decimal representation. The issue is when the decimal expansion terminates, in which case you can decrease the last digit by $1$ and append an infinite string of $9$s.